# Which ThreadPool config for highly synchronous application?

Tags: java, multithreading, playframework

In [Play's documention about ThreadPools](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ThreadPools#Highly-synchronous) it's recommended for highly synchronized Java web applications with a lot of blocking IO to 'use a very large number of threads in its pool'. In the example they use 200 to 300 parallel threads. My app reads files from a hard disk in most of the requests and nearly each request access a MySQL database via JPA, so I'd say it's pretty synchronized.

Now I did some stress test with [Gatling](http://gatling.io/#/) on my development laptop and compared the Play's default thread pool with the one recommended for synchronized web applications. Surprisingly I couldn't find any difference between both.

Do I the wrong kind of stress test? What kind of stress test should I do to see the difference in the two configs? Or do I misunderstand Play's documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your load test, make sure to you don't just run a few concurrent users that execute requests at fast pace. This way, you might get the number of requests per sec you want, but not the proper level of concurrency.

Make sure you run the proper number of concurrent users to match what you're expecting on your live system.

Comment: I use `setUp(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(3) during(1 minutes))).protocols(httpProtocol)` in the Gatling config. Each run with Gatling has 73 requests and pauses several times for several seconds in between. I'd think this are result in enough concurrent users, doesn't it?

Comment: So you have 219 concurrent users after 73s and I guess you probably top ~400 users. If your db queries and your file accesses are fast enough, it looks like you're fine. The issues with thread starvation arise when your IOs are not fast enough.

Comment: You can as long as your IOs are very fast. As soon as they'll slow down (eg long SQL queries), you'll have to switch.